# 1 output channel for image classification

Tags: pytorch

I have 22 classes, on the output layer, respectively, 22 channels, how can I change all this so that the output is 1 channel. Number 1 corresponds to class 1, number 2 - to the second, etc.

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5) 
            self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 64, 5)

            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 21 * 21, 120)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 256)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 22) 


        def forward(self, x):
            x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
            x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
            x = torch.flatten(x, 1) 
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
            x = self.fc3(x)
            return x


net = Net()
```

Comment: You could replace the return statement in your forward pass with: `return torch.argmax(x, dim=1) + 1`

Comment: i get such an error
"RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Long"  `import torch.optim as optim

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.0003, momentum=0.9)` [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18TFaUG9RKv8vUp4BaMZMEkgbV2UIGeQL#scrollTo=csTAveb-TZb4)

Comment: It says it expects class probabilities but you are returning class labels. Remove my suggestion above, because I think you've gotten it backwards (class labels should be `0:N-1`, NOT the outputs) and when you input it into your criterion use `torch.softmax(outputs)` to convert your model outputs into probabilities.

Comment: Thank you. But my model trains well, the probabilities come out on the output layer, but I want to get 1 output channel, because I use the resulting model in Unity in the ONNX format for performance. The more output channels, the lower the performance. Is this even possible? I'm a newbie in neural networks

Comment: To use that loss function you NEED to return the logits (raw outputs). You could just see if the model is in training using `if self.training()` and return the logits, otherwise return the `argmax` output.